# PHP require once class method

Tags: php, require

I have a file(**file.php)** which `require_once` a file in which is initialized all the objects(**init.php**). This file(**file.php**) is in the same folder as **init.php**. The communication between them is ok. But then i have a file(**file2.php**) which `require_once` the **init.php** and it is not in the same folder(**../../file2.php**). The require_once is going right but when i try to call a method `$db->select(...)` then i get a error:

```
`Call to a member function execute() on boolean in.
```

But when i put the same code in the file.php all is going right.

Init.php

```
<?php
require_once 'class/Database.php';
require_once 'class/UserRegister.php';
require_once 'class/Utility.php';
require_once 'class/AccountValidate.php';

$configs = include 'config.php';

$db = new Database($configs);
$db->Connect();


$utility = new Utility();

?>
```

file2.php

```
<?php 
require_once '../../php/init.php';
$db->select(array("*"),"users","username","=","test"); //not working ?>
```

Comment: Post some code, we cant see the future, let us see what you did.

Answer (score 0):

use a relative path to **FILE**, when using require_once in `file2.php`:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/../../init.php");
```

If your are using require_once() within `init.php` you should do the same, for example if you calla "database.php" include in the same directory of init.php

```
...
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/database.php");
...
```